# Media Query parse error in iphone 5

Tags: responsive-design

I am making a responsive site www.sandbox.mercomcorp.com and I am getting a parse error on wordpress in my css on my media query for iphone 5. I have no idea why

```
@media only screen and (device-height:568px) and (device-width:320px) and (-webkit-min-device pixel-ratio:2) and (orientation :landscape)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2`. You've got a space between device and pixel.